VMWare Player keeps autoinstalling Visual C++ redistributables even when they have been uninstalled and the computer is without network
I am preparing a document about installing VMWare Player. I did the installation once, and I remember the installer asking if it can download the necessary Visual C++ redistributables from the network.
Now, I want to do install it again to test if I can point the user to do manual redistributable installation first, to make it possible to install stuff offline. However now I have a problem.
Whatever I do, reinstalling the VMWare player automatically pulls the redistributables from somewhere.

I have uninstalled redistributables and VMWare Player, rebooted the machine, removed everything relevant in disk cleanup, and it still finds from somewhere the redistributables. I tried even without network and Windows was still able to automatically find the redistributables.
How do I remove the redistributables completely from my machine so I can write my document?

The redistributable installer is simply bundled with the VMWare Player installer. Bunch of applications include installers for dependencies within their offline installers, so that the user doesn't have to download and install it themselves.
They even have documentation for this for VMWare Tools, specifying the versions that will get installed. And according to it it shouldn't install whenever you have the same/newer version than the bundled one:

It is recommended to always keep Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable updated with the latest version available from Microsoft. If the installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable version is the same or newer than the version included with VMware Tools installer, it will not install its own version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable. This helps reduce the likelihood of system reboot during VMware Tools upgrade.

But it might be different for VMWare Player if you noticed it's always installed. You shouldn't worry about users installing it manually regardless.

This was actually the reason. I provisioned a new Windows machine and ran the installer offline. The redistributables got installed at the same time. It is possible that in some conditions the first installation process asks to access the internet for checking updates to the redistributables but I am not sure about it anymore. Thanks again.

It likely has both offline inclusion (some possibly older constant version) and online check (to install the latest).
